# New to SQL and can't get the code to filter more than one parameter

Tags: sql

Be gentle.  I'm still learning.  I have a report I'm trying to pull where I need to use the not equal to set three different things to exclude.  The report works fine with one not equal, but when I add a second, it ignores the date range and still includes what I'm filtering.

This is the one that works by using one not equal.  I'm filtering out any null/blank values out of the secondary name location.

```
SELECT distinct
                         Response_Master_Incident.Master_Incident_Number, Response_Master_Incident.Response_Date, Response_Master_Incident.Problem, Response_Master_Incident.Location_Name, Response_Master_Incident.Address, 
                         VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName
FROM            Response_Master_Incident INNER JOIN
                         VehicleLocations ON Response_Master_Incident.ID = VehicleLocations.MasterIncidentID
WHERE        (Response_Master_Incident.Response_Date > '08/01/2019') AND (Response_Master_Incident.Response_Date < '09/01/2019') AND (Response_Master_Incident.Problem = 'Escort Person') AND 
                         (Response_Master_Incident.Call_Disposition = 'TL - Transported Law') AND (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName <> '')

ORDER BY Response_Master_Incident.Response_Date
```

When I try to add two more using the 'or' statement, it ignores the date range and still includes them. This is what I'm trying to get it to do.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
                         Response_Master_Incident.Master_Incident_Number, Response_Master_Incident.Response_Date, Response_Master_Incident.Problem, Response_Master_Incident.Location_Name, Response_Master_Incident.Address, 
                         VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName
FROM            Response_Master_Incident INNER JOIN
                         VehicleLocations ON Response_Master_Incident.ID = VehicleLocations.MasterIncidentID
WHERE        (Response_Master_Incident.Response_Date > '08/01/2019') AND (Response_Master_Incident.Response_Date < '09/01/2019') AND (Response_Master_Incident.Problem = 'Escort Person') AND 
                         (Response_Master_Incident.Call_Disposition = 'TL - Transported Law') AND (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName <> '') OR
                         (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName <> 'Bradley County%') OR
                         (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName <> 'Tennova%')
ORDER BY Response_Master_Incident.Response_Date
```

Any help would be appreciated.

---

So this is a hypothetical of what I am getting as a return.

[image]

---

I tried replacing the "OR" with the "AND" and yes, it still returned outside of my date range and with the three places showing.

```
~SELECT DISTINCT 
              Response_Master_Incident.Master_Incident_Number, 
              Response_Master_Incident.Response_Date,
              Response_Master_Incident.Problem, 
              Response_Master_Incident.Location_Name, 
              Response_Master_Incident.Address, 
              VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName

FROM          Response_Master_Incident INNER JOIN
              VehicleLocations ON Response_Master_Incident.ID = 
              VehicleLocations.MasterIncidentID

WHERE        (Response_Master_Incident.Response_Date > '08/01/2019') AND 
             (Response_Master_Incident.Response_Date < '09/01/2019') AND 
             (Response_Master_Incident.Problem = 'Escort Person') AND 
             (Response_Master_Incident.Call_Disposition = 'TL - Transported 
             Law') AND 
             (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName <> '') AND
             (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName <> 'Bradley County%') AND
             (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName <> 'Tennova%')

ORDER BY     Response_Master_Incident.Response_Date~
```

Comment: I tried the AND earlier and it still ignores the date range and includes them in the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will *always* be true for *every* possible record:

```
(VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName <> '')
OR (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName <> 'Bradley County%')
OR (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName <> 'Tennova%')
```

Because, no matter what value is in `SecondaryLocationName`, it will *always* "not equal" one of those values.

To filter out the matching records, use `AND` instead of `OR`:

```
(VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName <> '')
AND (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName <> 'Bradley County%')
AND (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName <> 'Tennova%')
```

Side note: Maybe this is different for various database engines, but would `<>` make use of the `%` wildcard?  *Maybe* you meant to use the `LIKE` operator?:

```
(VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName <> '')
AND (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName NOT LIKE 'Bradley County%')
AND (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName NOT LIKE 'Tennova%')
```

Also note that `''` and `NULL` are not necessarily the same thing.  You may also want to include:

```
AND (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: I tried the AND and it does the same thing. Still leaves them in there and ignores the date range.

Comment: @Angela: Can you show what you tried, show sample input data, and sample output data, and what you expected the sample output data to be?

Comment: I'm not sure if this helps, but the SecondaryLocationName is an actual name of a place in the records.  I have three places I need to filter out and not show.  Nulls, anything beginning with Bradley County and anything beginning with Tennova.  I need all other records to show.

Comment: @Angela: This is how you'd filter those records.  If what you tried isn't working, show what you tried.  You could have a simple typo, and saying "I already tried" doesn't allow us to correct that typo.

Comment: I changed out the two "or" to the "and" and it still didn't work.  I can't really post the results because it has confidential information in there.   But the report tracks transports to certain locations to get mileage reimbursement.  Every location is eligible for reimbursement except the three I'm trying to filter out.

Comment: @Angela: *"I can't really post the results because it has confidential information in there"* - Replicate the problem with different information.  Simplify what you're doing by removing some of the other conditions and focusing specifically on where you think the problem is.  "I can't show you" also doesn't allow us to help much.

Comment: The wildcard % has been working correctly on my other reports and when I just use the one VehicleLocation.SecondaryLocationName <> ' ', it eliminates the nulls.  I'll study up more so I can learn to post what you need.

Comment: That combination worked!  By changing that part to this (the "null" didn't work), now it is doing everything correctly.  Thank you @David  ~(VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName not like 'Bradley County%') AND (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName not like 'Tennova%') AND (VehicleLocations.SecondaryLocationName not like '')~